# Apple spaces switching screens after sleeping

Tags: sleep-wake, spaces

I have a 2017 Macbook Pro. I connect to two external screens via a Belkin Thunderbolt 3 Express Dock HD. They are arranged external|external|internal left to right. I have my 'menu bar' dragged to the far left external screen in the Displays preference pane, which is where I want my dock (on the far left hand side).

My issue is that whenever I wake the machine from sleep, the internal and central screen switch spaces, which is *infuriating* as I have to drag them all back to the correct place all the time.

Some other places say try switching the screen the menu bar is on, but this isn't appropriate for me as it would move my dock position.

I have 'Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use' disabled in Mission Control settings.

Is there any way to solve this problem, so that the spaces remain on their correctly affiliated screens, or failing that a quick way I can (preferably with a keyboard shortcut) cause the spaces on screens 2/3 to switch all in one go without the laborious dragging of up to six spaces back and forth?

Answer (score 1):

Have you been doing an upgrade instead of clean install? If so, you will definitely find issues like these.

Try using Onyx - https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html to clear the caches and run some maintenance. Hopefully your issue should get solved.

Comment: I did upgrade from High Sierra, but I don't trust this program I'm afraid (especially giving it full-disk access). Is there any open-source tool I can use?

Comment: I don't know any open source tools but if you are afraid that it is gonna send something over the network, you can use the app called "Hands Off" and don't let Onyx send any data over the network. I am careful about installing apps as well so don't worry :) Also, if you have Google Chrome installed, I don't think any other app is gonna send over as much data as Google products do and you should be switching to Firefox :)